# request.method == "post" returns a false, but

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am adding data from a ModelForm to the db, but "if request.POST returns" a true, and if "request.method = 'post'" returns a false.  How can that be?  From what I understand it is supposed to work the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` is a dictionary. When it is not empty it returns `True`.

`request.method == 'POST'` (note the upper-case for `POST` and the double equal sign `==`) is checking the method.

I believe that you made `request.method = 'post'` which is clearly not what you meant.